# Sound doesn't work with update 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: sound, 14.10

After my Ubuntu updating (14.04 to 14.10), an Ubuntu none modified (on Unity), after doing a classical update with graphical update, et installation came fine, and restart much times after making all sudo apt-get update/grade/autoremove needed, without update happen anymore.

Material : Amilo Pi 2530 - Fujitsu
Update did by Ethernet, without network shutdown
Previous version: 14.04 (without problem), actual version: 14.10.

1/ One main error message: Sorry, an error occurred within software installation. Package: syslinux-themes-debian.

2/ No more Sound Card showed:
[image: sound configuration screenshot]

3/ Material:

```
********:~$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
```

4/ I tried this tutorial: [here](http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/) without success. AlsaMixer works fine for entry, detect material, but doesnt send outpout.

5/ PavuControl doesn't detect my material.

6/ I tried to uninstall and reinstall all, force services restart, restart computer, but nothing happen on my sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same audio device, and noticed an unknown modem drive in the "Additional Drivers" tab of the "Software & Updates" setting.

I tried disabling the unknown driver and sound instantly worked.  However upon restart the driver was re-enabled.

For a more permanent fix I removed the package "sl-modem-daemon" and after a restart the audio was working again.

```
********:~$ sudo apt-get purge sl-modem-daemon
```

After a restart the driver is disabled and sound is working again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So great!!!! Problem resolved thanks to you!! :)

Comment: Somethign similar to this solved it for me. I didn't have sl-modem-daemon. But installing it, rebooting and then uninstalling it actually solved the problem... weird.